# Given Manager And Employee Find All employees under manager in < O (N) time

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory

I was asked this in an interview:

Given subordinates and managers, construct a data structure (or use existing one) and then implement method `countReports(employeeId)` such that it prints the total direct and indirect reports.

I told that I would solve it by building a Graph and then compute the in degree of each vertex, and I told the time complexity as O(V+E). Then I was asked to solve this problem in < O(V) but I couldn't, am wondering if there is such solution.

```
/** 

subordinate, manager
A, C
B, C
C, F
D, E
E, F
F, F

countReports(employeeId) -> num // sum of direct and indirect reports for employee with id=employeeId

eg. 

A -> 0
C -> 2 // A, B
F -> 6 // C, E, F, A, B, D

Ask:
 * implement countReports
 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, the first structure appear in my mind:

```
Map<String,List<String>> mapEmployee = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

or

```
Map<String,Set<String>> mapEmployee = new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();
```

first loop, we iterate the list of input and build the above data structure. Complexity: O(N).

Then we can access the result by employeeId very quickly, complexity: O(1).

```
List<String> subordinates = mapEmployee.get(employee); O(1)
int result = subordinates.count(); // O(1)
```

PS: Use LinkedList might speed up when you add multiple subordinates.